# How do I shrink a matrix using an array mask in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, arrays, matrix, mask, reshape

This seems to be a very common problem of mine:

```
data = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
mask = [true false true];

mask = repmat(mask, 2, 1);

data(mask) ==> [1; 4; 3; 6]
```

What I wanted was `[1 3; 4 6]`.

Yes I can just `reshape` it to the right size, but that seems the wrong way to do it.  Is there a better way?  Why doesn't `data(mask)` return a matrix when it is actually rectangular?  I understand in the general case it may not be, but in my case since my original mask is an array it always will be.

**Corollary**

Thanks for the answer, I just also wanted to point out this also works with anything that returns a numeric index like `ismember`, `sort`, or `unique`.

I used to take the second return value from `sort` and apply it to every column manually when you can use this notion to do it one shot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will give you what you want:

```
>> data = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
>> mask = [true false true];
>> data(:,mask)

ans =

     1     3
     4     6
```

This works because you can simply apply the logical index `mask` to the columns, selecting all the rows with `:`.

Even when a 2-D logical array is used for an input, the output will be a column array of indexed values. This is because there is no guarantee that the indexed elements can be organized into a 2-D (i.e. rectangular) output. Consider if your 2-D mask were the following:

```
mask = [true false true; true false false];
```

This would index 3 values, which can't be organized into anything but a row or column vector for the output. Here's another example:

```
mask = [true true true; true false false];
```

This would index 4 values, but 3 are from the first row and 1 is from the second row. How should these values be shaped into a rectangular output matrix? Since there's no clear way to do this in general for an arbitrary 2-D index matrix, a column vector of indexed values is returned.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple like that.  Never considered using the : notion with an mask.  I've only used a single index.